# Finding a valuation

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Shafarevich, in *Basic Algebraic Geometry I*, makes the following definition, which I'm having trouble understanding in a concrete example.  Let $X$ be a variety, nonsingular in codimension 1, and let $C$ be an irreducible codimension 1 subvariety.  Let $U$ be some affine open subset of $C$, which consists of nonsingular points, and such that $C$ is defined by some local equation in $U$.  Then the ideal of $C$ in $k[U]$ is $(\pi)$.  On the way to defining the divisor associated to a rational function $f \in k(X)$, he defines $\nu_C(f)$ to be the nonnegative integer $r$ such that $f \in (\pi^r)$ but $f \not\in (\pi^{r+1})$, and proves that this is well-defined and independent of the choice of affine neighborhood.

I'm trying to understand this definition in a concrete example.  Let $C$ be the prime divisor $Z(x_0)$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$, and let $f \in k[D(x_0)]$ have degree $d$.  Then a local equation of $C$ in $D(x_i)$ is $x_0/x_i$, so to calculate $\nu_C(f)$, I need to find an integer $r$ such that $(x_0/x_i)^r$ divides $f$ in $k[D(x_i)]$.  But looking at explicit $f$ makes this not seem possible to me.  For instance, how could $f \in k(\mathbb{P}^2)$ defined by $f=\frac{x_1^2+x_1x_2}{x_0^2}$ be expressed as a multiple of $(x_0/x_1)^r$ in $k[D(x_1)]$?  Am I confusing the definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactely, if $f$ is a rational function over $C$, then $\nu_C(f)$ is defined as $\nu_C(h)-\nu_C(g)$ where $f=\frac{h}{g}$ and $h,g$ are both regular funtions over $X$.

In your case, we can write $f$ as $(1+\frac{x_2}{x_1})/(\frac{x_0}{x_1})^2$, so $\nu_C(f)$ is $-2$.

Comment: I guess I see this, but I'm a little confused then.  I want to show that $(f)+\nu_C(f)C$ is effective.  How can this be true if $\nu_C(f)=-d$ (using the notation of the question)?

Comment: It would seem to me that $(f)-dE=(g)-d(x_0)-dE=(g)-2dE$ in this case?

Comment: @user127542 The assertion is not correct. For example, let $X$ be $\mathbb P^1$, and $f=\frac{x_1^2}{(x_0-x_1)(x_0-2x_1)}$, and $C=[1:1]$. Then $(f)=2[1:0]-[1:1]-[2:1]$ and $\nu_C(f)=-1$. So, maybe you should check the assertion again.